# Saitek P380 Gamepad 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, gamepad

I have found a Saitek P380 gamepad and would greately like to use it on my Ubuntu 14.04 64bit computer. I have looked on the saitek website for drivers to run through wine but to no avail. If you really want specifics then I would like it to play 2 player steam games such as portal 2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is proberly a steam/game issue.

Many games ONLY support x-input (Xbox 360 compatable controllers) but this can vary from game to game.

The gamepad you mention is direct-input, this started to be phased out years ago.

If you have the correct button layout (2 sticks, 4 shoulder, 4 face, a d-pad,select and start buttons, you can try the following driver.

[X-input emulator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327640/how-to-emulate-xinput-device-with-directinput-gamepad)

Though you may run into issues with certain games as this is an x-input emulator and may have issues.