# How to get Defender Omega USB gamepad to work?

Tags: 22.04, gamepad

Please help me get a Defender Omega USB gamepad to work on Ubuntu 22.04. It is an "off brand" PS3-like controller.

I'm running Ubuntu on an Orange Pi 5.

It has an "analog" switch on it. In default mode `lsusb` detects it as an Xbox 360 controller. But evtest does not register any key being pressed. xboxdrv detects it and says that it created js0 and event 15 for it, but js0 never created or found.

If I hold the "analog" switch for 5 seconds, a LED lights up. In this mode lsusb detects it as some Chinese company name controller.

evtest sees it as PS3 controller and detects every button press and printing out key press data, key codes and values.

In both modes jstest-gtk doesn't see it as a gamepad and js0 file is never created.

I tested it in pcsxr an fceux and they see its buttons on "analog" mode, but mednafen and its front end mednaffe does not see it.

And I also noticed that there is no mouse0 in the dev/input directory for mouse, but mouse is working.

Is there any way to get it to be recognised as a gamepad with js0 file being created and jstest being able to see it, or maybe at least to map its input events as keyboard key presses? I want to use it for a NES emulator so I don't really need analog sticks input.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327640/how-to-emulate-xinput-device-with-directinput-gamepad) helps, direct input to xinput.